# Multiline find & replace in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to replace

```
import Quick
import Nimble
```

with

```
import XCTest
```

Is it possible to do it in Xcode find and replace or I have to use Xcode regular expressions?

I have tried: import Quick\nimport Nimble but it doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 2):

**THE FAST WAY:**

You can simply copy both lines dragging with the mouse and the paste them on find textfield.

***THE COOL LEEMUR'S WAY:***

But also there is a great way to find expressions:

- Press **CMD + f**
- A **find field** will appear on the **top** of the editor.
- At the right side of the find field there is a **"+"** sign
  [image]
- Press "+" will display a **list of special characters**
  [image]
- Its very useful, you can make something similar to regular expressions, **mixing literal text with patterns** [image]
- You can try to find the expression just in the **current file** writing it in the top find field. Or you can try to find the expression in the **whole project** using the Find Navigation tab on the left. As you will see the expression will appear there also.
- Moreover if you want you can use an **actual regular expression** to find something if you press in the word **"Contains"** at the left of the **"+"** sign. It will show a list where you can select the option **"Regular Expression"**
- If you want to find text select "**Find**" at the left of the editor. If you want to replace it, select "**Replace**" and a new field will appear below.
- You can **replace the text with another pattern**, using some of the words that you used to find the text. If you **double clic** on "**Word1**" at the **find field** it will appear at the **replace field**.
- In this example I'm changing the order of two words around MyText[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find for multiline text and replace it (cmd+opt+f) with new text. make sure to copy and paste multiline text as it is written on the Xcode file.

[image: Replace multiple line text]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you tried and failed. But I tried and it worked. Procedures as bellow:

1. First select and copy the lines you wanna replace.
2. `Shift+Option+CMD+F` to open `Find navigator` in Xcode, then `CMD+V` to paste the multiline text.
3. You can also choose a scope for search. Then input the new line.